# RubyOnRails - Sorting members by last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a lot of members in database and I want them sort in Rails by last_name, but the trick is that last name contain croatian letters like (Č,Ć,Š,Đ,Ž).

Some of last_names are for example: Antić, Čekić, Živad, Đurak, Perić...

I used [ffi-locale gem](https://github.com/k3rni/ffi-locale) but i failed to sort it. So any help and advice is good!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You should use proper database table collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database has a correct configuration, this should work:

```
Member.sort(last_name: :asc).all
```

If you want to sort the members in your application, after fetching them from the database, you could use `sort` function (it works fine with utf strings):

```
members.sort_by!(&:last_name)
```